# Search Multi string in Multi file and print the "result for each file in one line"

Tags: linux

I have the following problem with a search method in Linux: I want to search multiple strings (e.g. `text1`, `text2` and `text3`) in all files in a folder. I want to find all lines that contain these strings and *print the result for each file in only one line*.

I used `grep` and `awk` but the result is always spread over multiple lines. Can anybody help me to find a good method for that?

Please note that there can be multiple matches of some of the search strings within a single file, like two times `text3`, and i need both of them in output.

Comment: Please specify more clearly what the result is supposed to look like (perhaps give an example), by editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
grep -Er "string 1|string 2|string 3" /folder|\
awk '{COLON1=index($0,":")
      FILE=substr($0,1,COLON1)
      if (FILE!=PREVFILE) { printf "\n"FILE": "} else printf " % "
      printf "%s",substr($0,COLON1+1)
      PREVFILE=FILE
     }
     END {print "\n"}'
```

This puts all results for each file on one line, each result (if more than one) is separated by ' % '. It will search all files in the specified folder (but not any subfolders). I've put it on multiple lines for ease of comprehension, but it can be done as a one-liner - just use semi-colons between the awk commands instead of newlines.